# How to send body in a HTTP Get Request Angular 9

Tags: angular, rest, http-get

I could send a body(json) in Postman for a GET request.

[image]

My Problem is I am not able to do the same in my yes-no.service.ts file.

```js
getYesNoDropdowns() {
  return this.http.get(AppComponent.lookUpListUrl, { headers: headers });
}
```

How do I achieve this? I have to use only Get.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body a detailed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posts have a body, gets do not. You will need to put the data on the query string if you are using a get.

Comment: Thanks @adrian-brand, I am aware that posts have body as per the API I want to get data from, it has to be a get request and I have to send the data in the body like I did in postman which is working fine. I could not pass the body into the HTTP get() method. Can you please show syntactically what you meant by sending a query string?

Comment: `?data=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(yourBodyObject))}` and you can use decodeURIComponent on the server

Comment: I am not allowed to modify anything on the server, I can only make API requests. How is it that I am able to do it using Postman?

Comment: Postman allows you to construct any request you want, the Angular http service follows the standard.

Comment: Then above isn't answering the question or providing a solution, Why is this marked as correct answer